# How to right align angular Material vertical tabs

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have vertical material tabs as shown in below image.

[image]

I want to position those tabs to right and content to left side. How can I do that.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z3v4u?file=src%2Findex.html)

I have achieved vertical tabs using css flex.( using below css)

```
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-group {
  flex-direction: row;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-header {
  border-bottom: none;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-header-pagination {
  display: none !important;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-labels {
  flex-direction: column;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-ink-bar {
  height: 100%;
  left: 98% !important;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

I  just want to have the tabs to the right side of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` instead of `row`. It make tabs position to the right edge, also for the vertical bar. If you want the width of bar is always 2% and in between content & label (like in example), then use:

```
:host /deep/ .mat-ink-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2% !important;
}
```

Full code & [stackblitz demo](http://stackblitz.com/edit/material-vertical-tabs-right):

```
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-group {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-header {
  border-bottom: none;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-header-pagination {
  display: none !important;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-labels {
  flex-direction: column;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-ink-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2% !important;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```